# Distribution notation

Tags: normal-distribution, terminology, iid

beginner here.

I've seen in a paper $x\sim NIID(0,1)$ and $y\sim N(0,1)$.

This confuses me: to me these both look like standard Normal variables. Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: NIID probably means [Normallu, Identically, and Independently Distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables), but it should refer to more than one distribution. Could you link the paper to avoid confusion?

Comment: It is bad notation but the first must refer to a sequence of normally distributed random variables while the second is just a single normal random variable.

Comment: It could for example be that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both $N(0,1)$. The first statement probably is to be shorthand for saying that they are independent of each other, while the second is compatible with saying that the correlation coefficient of $x_1$ and $x_2$, $\rho$, is nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

[$NIID(\mu,\sigma^2$)](https://books.google.ca/books?id=VvuHDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=niid(0,1)&source=bl&ots=jKtwSQk4ur&sig=Ui9G5R3iht8EmMR1fqkInv8392M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdgc_-iJXXAhXL7YMKHfhDBkgQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=niid(0%2C1)&f=false) appears in the context of normally identically and independently distributed and is also referred to as [$NID(\mu,\sigma^2$)](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/sta6208/notes1.pdf) without apparent loss of generality.

The difference between those and $N(\mu,\sigma^2$) is that iid (identically and independently distributed) is an additional assumption that implies that one measurement of a RV has no correlation or relation to any other measurement. For example, one can test for runs, or [turning-points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turning_point_test), or [autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation), that would make a distribution NOT iid.

It is probably better notation to specify that $N(\mu,\sigma^2$) is iid, and the best notation is just to use words, rather than acronyms and symbols.